# Migration How to pass Connection String into Library Project (.netStandard)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-standard

My solution has 3 Projects:

- Entity(include Dbcontext,...), target framework .NetStandard 1.4, project type library
- WebApi
- WebUi
- I want to create function migrate into Entity Project. In Entity project, I have a class ApplicationContextFactory

  ```
  public class ApplicationContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>
  {
      public ApplicationContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
      {
          var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>();
          return new ApplicationContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
      }
  }
  ```

I want to pass Connection string from WebAPI to Entity project
My StartUp Class (WebAPI)

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
```

but when I use command Add-Migration InitialMigration then I got an error :

```
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

Comment: Hello, can you reveal your DbContext class?
It seems that you are not properly using the options model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. because in my solution that has 2 projects are WebUI and WebAPI, I just set as startup project of WebAPI which contains the connection string and it works well